# What is the best way to keep Stack Overflow strong now that we have ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, community, chatgpt

I saw an article, [After ChatGPT disruption, Stack Overflow lays off 28 percent of staff](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/10/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff/). Stack Overflow helps me a ton. I suspect many AI's knowledge comes from user-generated content on the Internet... so that part needs to stay healthy.

So what can we do, as users, to keep Stack Overflow healthy?

Some ideas to kick start the conversation:

- add a donate button, like on Wikipedia
- upsell Stack Overflow users on things that aren't critical. Like [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord)
- uh, use Stack Overflow more?

Side note/clarification:
I use ChatGPT (and the Google and Microsoft equivalent). They are useful tools. Stack Overflow is a useful too.

Comment: This question appears to be specific to Stack Overflow. You posted this on Meta Stack Exchange, which is the meta site for the whole network. Stack Overflow has its own meta site: https://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: For SE (the company), a starting point would be keeping CMs and stopping ignoring the community </rant>

Comment: To actually answer the question you asked for users: continue to do moderation tasks. The queues, flagging/closing questions, voting (on content), etc. Participating on Meta, both MSO and MSE, can also be helpful/beneficial, but it can also be... frustrating and challenging at times, too. Of course, posting high quality questions/answers is also good

Comment: I think it’s a bit of a stretch to come to the conclusion that ChatGPT caused the layoff. Just because some article said that in a clickbait-y headline does not make it fact. So the premise of this whole post is kinda flawed.

Comment: I'd  also like to point out this comment from the article https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/10/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff/?comments=1&comments-page=1 which lays out the *actual* value of Q&A better than anyone else

Comment: The article keeps going on about Stack Overflow being a forum. Including saying, and I quote "*You might think of Stack Overflow as "just a forum"*". This doesn't really imply a great understanding on the part of the author of the article.

Comment: At least there are some thoughtful user comments. [For example](https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff.1496474/post-42274759), *"Based on my use of LLM-based code tools over the last year or so, that first paragraph is excessively, wildly, enormously overstating the abilities of AI code tools in late 2023. Then goes on to stunningly overstate the feasibility of human checking."*

Comment: And [a new synonym](https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff.1496474/post-42275981): Staff Overflow (It should be taken in the right spirit.)

Comment: How would they upsell on Discord? Can you elaborate? (Not rhetorical questions.)

Answer (score 21):

Over the years, communities have suffered *not* because of external threats but internal ones. Frankly our woes have less to do with our Q&A sites losing relevance than forgetting that the community *built* this network and focusing on things other than that to the *detriment* of the Stack Exchange Q&A.

Historically downsizings have been due to SE's 'other' projects, careers and teams getting pushed *hard*, with a heavy marketing and *hiring* focus on that. Last year, SO Inc. doubled their *sales* staff - and that team apparently took the worst hit. We also generally seem to lose some of our most experienced and beloved CMs and staff as part of the downsizing (not that we value any person who works with us less!) - which indicates the people making this decisions seem unaware of the impact people have had.

Frankly, the company has to do better by *us*, and expecting the community to pick up where they have consistently dropped the ball is unfair.

*If* I felt the company actually had our interests at heart - I would say being an advocate for the company's *paid products* such as Teams, either as a decision maker, or as a individual contributor would be a start.

The platform ... doesn't matter. The communities and people do. That there's anything *left* is a testament to the very strong foundation we have. That said, the strongest foundations can weather away.

We keep the network strong by fighting the good fight. We share our knowledge, we help new users find their feet. We stay mindful of the impact we have on those we touch. AI could give you answers *fast*, but sometimes, you need answers from someone who actually understands the problem. Frankly, we'll survive AI. Surviving management decisions such as "We'll downsize the community team, it'll be fine" or antagonizing the community that contributes for short term goals - I'm less sure about. If Stack Overflow *falls*, something else can fill the void for you. Perhaps Codidact, or something completely different. The company and platform needs the *people*, not the other way around.